# Can two two C++ projects refer each other?

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style

I have two separate projects in eclipse.
Project A needs to refer to Project B and project B needs to refer to project A.

> Is it possible and wise to refer each other ?

**Updated**:

*ProjectB uses many classes of Project A (kind of library) and Project A needs only a particular class of Project B (since Project A's received an object of the class in project B, and so Project A needs that class to type_cast and do something)*

Comment: Circular dependencies aren't such  good idea. There's a number of techniques to decouple such dependencies, namely providing imported/exported interfaces.

Comment: Does Project A need to refer to *parts* of Project B?  The idea is to refactor the projects into useful pieces that can be shared.

Comment: Are the two project standalone executable, or one is compiled as static lib ?

Comment: This really depends on what/how you are referring from one project to another. Can you give some more details of what you actually trying to do?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ProjectB uses many classes of `Project A` (kind of library) and `Project A` needs only a particular class of `Project B` (since `Project A's` received an object of the class in `project B`, and so `Project A` needs that class to `type_cast` and do something)

Comment: Like I said or inferred, make project A use the files it needs.  Make project B use the files it needs.  If you are referring to libraries, make smaller libraries, such as Project C which contains code shared by project A and project B.  If the libraries are static, don't worry about including them.  The linking phase will extract only what it needs.

Comment: If I don't refer to either projects how can one project use another projects's Classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible with eclipse, I guess no. But it certainly is not a good idea.

References should go in one direction, avoiding loops. Let's say you want to reference code from A in B but find that B also needs code from A. The you could try to move these parts of code from A to B.

If this does not make sense, create a new project C with the common code used by both A and B.

By the way, this is not really related to C++. It makes sense in any programming language and even in non-programming projects.

Edit: After reading one of your comments, ("... Project A needs only a particular class of Project B (since Project A's received an object of the class ... ") it looks like you could solve this issue with some kind of dependency injection:

The class in A should not depend on the class defined in B but on a general interface (abstract class) from which the specific class in B is derived. Only when B uses A, it passes an object of the specific class. Ok, that was very brief, if you need more explanation, just search for dependency injection, this is definitely an important concept.

Comment: Please explain `dependency injection` with a sample example. I am new to this concept

Comment: @UtkalSinha: Have added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, software units may refer to software units.

A project is a container of one or more software units. A project may also have attributes such as include directories and libraries (software units).

You will want to refactor the projects so that they can share software units.  Don't worry about "referring" to common things like include paths and program settings.  You may be able to place these attributes into environment variables.

If a single function in a file of many functions needs to be shared, place it into a separate file.  Similarly with classes.